# joining two select queries where value of first query is used in second select query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How to join  two select statement where the result of first select statement is used in second select statement

Example:
**query 1**:

```
SELECT C.columnDescription, A.accounnumber, C.AcroColumn   
  FROM table_1 A JOIN table_2 B ON NVL(A.column1, A.column2) = B.column1, table_3 C 
 WHERE A.column4 = 'Apple' AND C.column1 = 'Apple' AND A.column6 = C.column2 AND  B.column2 = '00'
   AND C.column9 = 'N' AND (B.column5 = 'K' OR B.column8 = 'T')  ORDER BY A.column6;
```

**query 2**:

```
Select column_2, column_3 from **table_4** where **column_4 from table_4 = accounnumber which we get from table_1
```

which we got from previous select query.

Doing

```
SELECT C.columnDescription, A.accounnumber, C.AcroColumn   
  FROM table_1 A JOIN table_2 B ON NVL(A.column1, A.column2) = B.column1, table_3 C , table_4 D
 WHERE (D.column_2,D.column_3 in (select A.accounnumber FROM table_1 A JOIN table_2 B
    ON NVL(A.column1, A.column2) = B.column1 )
  A.column4 = 'Apple' AND C.column1 = 'Apple' AND A.column6 = C.column2 AND  B.column2 = '00'
   AND C.column9 = 'N' AND (B.column5 = 'K' OR B.column8 = 'T')  ORDER BY A.column6;
```

**taking forever to execute the query**

Comment: How is the result in the final query not right?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this does what you want:

```
Select column_2, column_3
from table_2
where column_4 in (Select column_1 from table_1);
```

If your problem is duplicated rows, then this will fix that problem.

EDIT:

A more efficient version is:

```
Select column_2, column_3
from table_2
where exists (Select column_1 from table_1 where table_1.column_1 = table_2.column4);
```

You should have an index on `table_1(column_1)`:

```
create index idx_table1_column1 on table_1(column_1);
```

Comment: I tried this but it is taking very long time to execute the query

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try a nested join

```
select column_2, column_3 from table_2 t2
join (select column_1, column_2 from table_1) t1 on t1.column_2 = t2.column_2
```

Maybe you should try turning your queries into views and substitute tables in your query for the views?